# How to run two different IP ranges in one VLAN

Tags: networking

Someone please help out of the mentioned scenario...

I have a campus wide network which has COMPUTER LABS for Students, OFFICES, and Wi-Fi users. Out of all these I have 07 computer labs where I have machines with dual booting option on windows (one runs 192.168.0.1/19 and other runs 172.16.0.0/24).

The purpose of keeping dual boot is as: on one OS Win 7 is for students usage it runs on 192.168.0.0/19 series. The other Win XP is used for Online Examinations and runs on 172.16.0.0/24 series.

I want to keep these 07 labs isolated from the entire network when the Online Examinations are going on i.e. when running 172.16.0.0/24 series. But the same labs are also used by students for the academic usage and at that time 192.168.0.0/19 series work as they use Win 7 OS.

In my setup I have following:
1. Layer 3 switch in the server room.

2. All the mentioned labs have OFC uplinks from Server Room to labs.
3. All the mentioned labs have one Layer 2 Switch, under these switches I have three unmanaged switches to provide /extend connectivity to the machines/PC's.

What I did:
1. I configure 04 ports on the L2 switch in the lab to run VLAN 2 and used these ports to provide uplinks to unmanaged switches.

2. I configured the OFC link from the lab to Server Room as a tagged port to run VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 on them.
3. In Server room on L3 switch also I configured the OFC uplink ports to tagged ports to support both the VLANs.
4. I configured 04 port on L3 switch to run VLAN 2 to connect the Online Examination Servers when the online examinations run.
5. I tried to ping the server ip in server room (172.16.0.1/24) from the lab machine 172.16.0.10/24 but it did not pinged.

Comment: its not really clear what you are trying to do but VLANs and subnets are completely independant from each other

Comment: I am trying to isolate the mentioned 07 computer labs from rest of the campus wide network, but these labs should support both the IP series of network.

Comment: It is very easy to run 2 IP sets in 1 VLAN. Set your primary VLAN IP to 172.16.0.1 / 24 and add e secondary one (like 192.168.0.1).  Command for this is "ip address IP MASK secondary" where IP is your secondary IP and MASK it's mask.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be for ETS, would it? I run an ETS test lab at a small college, and they do support Windows 7 now. We just have a specific user account we have the test proctors log into when setting up the room on our Windows 7 lab that is also open to students at other times.

Answer (score 0):

So you would like the machines to be either in one VLAN or in the other VLAN depending on if the one or the other system is booted (dual boot).

This is possible if the network cards and the their drivers you use in Windows support VLAN / tagging.

You would need to:

- Configure VLAN id and tagging on each of the computers and for each of the boot option, so the one boot option uses VLAN 1 and the other VLAN 2
- Configure the corresponding ports on the switch to send and receive tagged packets

See for an example: https://communities.intel.com/thread/40955

Comment: I am trying to isolate the mentioned 07 computer labs from rest of the campus wide network, but these labs should support both the IP series of network.

Comment: @Sauresh Mehrotra - so just put them into one VLAN and add IP adress or addresses you need - for each boot option separately

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get two subnets to coexist in the same vlan, you get the computers to use a different vlan depending on which OS boots up. To make this happen you need to do two things:

The first step is to configure the ports on your network switch(es). Set the ports so the default (untagged/native) vlan is the existing vlan for your lab (Windows 7). Then set the ports to also be *tagged* members of a new vlan that you'll set up to use the Windows XP 172.16.0.0/24 range. Don't forget to also tag both ends of any trunk ports you may need, and if you need to setup a new dhcp scope, ip-helper addresses, or routes on your switches and routers you should do that now, too.

Then we get to step two. What you have to do now is boot up the machines in the Windows XP and set the network card in that OS to tag its traffic with the new vlan ID. Open up the device manager and look at the properties for your network card. You'll end up with a window that looks something like this:

[image: Network Card Configuration]
<sup>I took this from Windows 8.1, but this dialog hasn't really changed since Windows 2000.</sup>

Here's where it gets tricky. Not all network cards support what we want to do here. If your card supports it, one of the tabs on this window (likely "Advanced") will have an option that lets you set a vlan tag for the card. Intel cards generally do support this. The cheap Realtek card I used to take the screen shot does not support it (I'll replace this with a better screenshot later when I'm at work where we have cards that can do this).

Once you set this option, it will only apply while you are running the Windows XP OS. Thus the computers will appear to be on vlan when running Windows XP, and another vlan when running Windows 7, and the computers will be isolated from the rest of the network when set up for the testing lab.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel Coel, but what if my LAN cards does not allow to add VLAN ID's and another question which arises in my mind is :

Comment: If I create Port based VLAN on L2 Switch and make 03 Tagged ports to run VLAN 1 & 2 both and use these ports to provide uplinks to Unmanaged switches then by default all the traffic generated by the machines will fall in the VLAN which is identified by the IP Subnet. And to run this I should create IP Subnet VLANS in my L3 switch in Server room. Will this work ???

Comment: The traffic will not fall into vlan by subnet after passing through an unmanaged switch. Depending on the switch, it will either drop the vlan tag (more likely) and _everything_ that comes back will be on the native vlan for the unmanaged switch, or it will handle the packets unchanged, and they'll be in a vlan by tag. Generally, don't use unmanaged switches upstream towards your server room from this switch. But if you have managed switches, then it will work once you create the vlans and configure all the appropriate ports.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I tried your way and it worked. Can I get your mail id for future comm. Kindly mail me at saureshmehrotra@its.edu.in, sauresh@hotmail.com

Thanks for your help once again

Comment: Joel Coel, I now have all the machines working fine but on 60 machines I have "Atheros L1 Gigabit Ethernet LAN Card" on these LAN cards the drivers are not showing the VLAN options... how can I add VLAN on these cards.

Comment: If the card doesn't support it, you're out of luck :( You may need to purchase a card that will do this to install the computers. If you hunt around, you should be able to find something for less than $10 per card. Remember: you only need to do this for that one specific lab. Everywhere else you still control the vlan through the switch port.